# Read csv file using Prometheus

Tags: csv, prometheus

I have data in csv formate, I want to add that data into prometheus please any help me.
Are there any exporter exist or API etc.

Answer (score 3):

You need an exporter that exposes the data from the CSV files over HTTP in Prometheus format, so that Prometheus can scrape it.

See, for example, https://github.com/stohrendorf/csv-prometheus-exporter if it does what you want.

Alternatively, you can expose the raw data directly from your application with a [Prometheus client library](https://prometheus.io/docs/instrumenting/clientlibs/) or use this to create your own customised exporter.