# Load CSV data to Prometheus

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-blackbox-exporter

I have a large csv dataset in the following format:

> time, id, v1, v2, ..., vn

I want to load this dataset in Prometheus. The dataset covers hundreds of time series data covering 3-4 months of high-granularity data points. The timestamps belong to the year 2019, so it's historical data, and I want to load it all at once to Prometheus to be able to query it.

I have checked similar [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64477723/read-csv-file-using-prometheus) [csv-prometheus-exporter](https://github.com/stohrendorf/csv-prometheus-exporter) but that did not work for me as I am unable to load the csv file in Prometheus.

I also aimed to convert the CSV file to OpenMetrics format as suggested by many independent repositories but none of it worked.

Is there an up-to-date way to load data from a csv file to Prometheus?

Comment: Could you elaborate, you want one time load data from your CSV file to Prometheus?

Comment: I added details to the question, thanks!

Comment: For such old data I'd recommend investigate [backfilling](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/storage/#backfilling-from-openmetrics-format). But for this you'll ned to convert your data to OpenMetrics  metrics format first.